# Está "outro alguém" correto?

Tags: pronomes

Eu estava ouvindo Raul Seixas, especificamente *Gospel*, e nela ele fala:

> "Por que que aquele que você quer tão bem já tem sempre ao seu lado outro alguém?"

Como músico ele tem licença poética, então, sendo culto ou não, ele estaria certo em dizer *outro alguém*. Mas quando não há licença poética, quando se escreve do culto, podemos usar *outro alguém*?

Se possível, generalizo a pergunta a *algum(a) outro(a) **X*** e conseqüentemente *algum alhures*, *algum outrem* e *outro nenhures*.

Comment: Em Portugal é muito comum. Ouve-se em letras de música em todo o lado.

Comment: o correto seria OUTRA PESSOA ou MAIS ALGUÉM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sim, está correto, porque "alguém" não é apenas um pronome, mas também um substantivo masculino, com o [significado](https://www.aulete.com.br/algu%C3%A9m) de "pessoa":

> sm.
> **3**. Ser humano, pessoa (considerada como indivíduo qualquer, que não se distingue, ou como ente singular): *Procura um alguém para amar: Sentia-se como apenas um alguém entre tantos outros anônimos.*

ou [também](https://dicionario.priberam.org/algu%C3%A9m)

> 2. Pessoa importante.

Já "alhures" e "nenhures" são advérbios e "outrem", pronome, então esses normalmente não admitiriam artigo (embora "outrem", e.g., me pareça substantivável).

Comment: A resposta é exatamente essa, não creio que virá outra.  Eu apenas acrescentaria que o substantivo "alguém" também pode significar "pessoa importante", como em "ele estuda muito, na esperança de vir a ser alguém na vida".

Comment: @Centaurus Feito.